# Can we use y=vx for non-homogeneous first order linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

below is an example of a  non-homogeneous first order linear differential equation

$yy'=x^3+y^2/x$

Yet, I found that I can solve it with y=vx, which as far as I know, is only for homogeneous cases.

$$yy'=x^3+y^2/x\\
yy'=\frac{x^4+y^2}{x}\\
y'=\frac{x^4+y^2}{xy}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(αx)^4+(αy)^2}{(αx)(αy)}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(α^2)x^4+y^2}{xy}$$

There’s an extra $α^2$.

Here comes the solution:

Let $y=vx$
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}\\
v+x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{x^4+v^2*x^2}{v*x^2}$$
Eliminate $x^2$,

$$v+x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{x^2+v^2}{v}$$

Moving the v to the right,

$$x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{x^2}{v}\\
v dv=x dx$$

Do the integration,

$$v^2/2=(x^2/2)+ c$$,where c is a constant

So, is there any exception for $y=vx$? Or am I wrong from the beginning where the differential equation is indeed homogeneous?

Comment: Your observation looks correct to me. The equation is not homogeneous, yet it responds to the same method. Interesting!

Comment: The $y=vx$ works for every homogeneous case, that fact that it works for this non-homogeneous case does not mean it will work on another though!

Comment: Agree with @Maesumi: you just got lucky. Nobody can stop you from trying $y=vx$ ansatz on any ODE whatsoever, yet in general it won't help one bit. And, by the same token, there will be many cases where it helps to get to solution, but it's not clear how to recognize which cases those are.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You can use mathjax to format your post and make it easier to read.

Comment: @DoctorBatmanGod  I believe the first line/equation was edited incorrectly. $x$ is in denominator (as in the third line) not in exponent.

Comment: @Maesumi Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Your first manipulation is wrong:
$$yy′=x^3+(y^{2/x}) \;\;\not\mspace{-10mu}\implies yy′=\frac{x^4+y^2}{x}.$$
However, taking the latter equation as the one you *actually* solve, I'd say (based on the algebra) that you just got lucky with the cancellation.  It happens.

Comment: I saw my friend using Bernoulli to solve it, guess everything is possible in mathematics

Comment: @jasoncurious Actually, that one is a Bernoulli equation if you divide by $y$ and distribute the $1/x$.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not linear** differential equation -> **yy′**=x3+**y2**/x
However it is solvable by linear sub eqution:
y'y=(y^2)'/2, substitue u = y^2, you get:
u'/2=x^3+u/x, u'x+ 2u = 2x^4, u'x^2-2xu=2x^5, u'/x^2 - 2/x^3*u = 2x, (u/x^2)' = 2x, u can go on from that..

Comment: You should use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/258310) to format your answer.